# Finding Intersections Region Based Trajectories vs. Line Trajectories

Tags: python, polygon, geospatial, spatial

I have two trajectories (i.e. two lists of points) and I am trying to find the intersection points for both these trajectories. However, if I represent these trajectories as lines, I might miss real world intersections (just misses).

What I would like to do is to represent the line as a polygon with certain width around the points and then find where the two polygons intersect with each other.

I am using the python spatial library but I was wondering if anyone has done this before. Here is a picture of the line segments which don't intersect because they just miss each other. Below is the sample data code that represents the trajectory of two objects.

[image]

[image]

```
object_trajectory=np.array([[-3370.00427248,  3701.46800775],
   [-3363.69164715,  3702.21408203],
   [-3356.31277271,  3703.06477984],
   [-3347.25951787,  3704.10740164],
   [-3336.739511  ,  3705.3958357 ],
   [-3326.29355823,  3706.78035903],
   [-3313.4987339 ,  3708.2076586 ],
   [-3299.53433345,  3709.72507366],
   [-3283.15486406,  3711.47077376],
   [-3269.23487255,  3713.05635557]])
target_trajectory=np.array([[-3384.99966703,  3696.41922372],
   [-3382.43687562,  3696.6739521 ],
   [-3378.22995178,  3697.08802862],
   [-3371.98983789,  3697.71490469],
   [-3363.5900481 ,  3698.62666805],
   [-3354.28520354,  3699.67613798],
   [-3342.18581931,  3701.04853915],
   [-3328.51519511,  3702.57528111],
   [-3312.09691577,  3704.41961271],
   [-3297.85543763,  3706.00878621]])
plt.plot(object_trajectory[:,0],object_trajectory[:,1],'b',color='b')
plt.plot(vehicle_trajectory[:,0],vehicle_trajectory[:,1],'b',color='r')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "representing a line as a polygon"? A polygon is made up of lines. Do you mean you want to find where the points, or lines in between the points, come within a certain threshold of the other trajectory?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JeremyMcGibbon . Basically I want an envelope around each line. The envelope would be represented as a polygon. And then I can identify where the two envelopes intersect with each other and then do more analysis on those points of intersection. Consider the plot image. In this situation, neither line intersects each other, but in the practical situation, it does because its not a line and has width to it. Does that help?

Comment: How well-sampled are the points? Is it sufficient to check for overlaps only in the viscinity of points, or do you need to look also at the trajectory in between those points? And how many points are your trajectories, as an order of magnitude?

Comment: What I mean is, if we have the two lines where we're checking for intersections, is it necessary that you check every single possible location along that line, or would it be enough to check only where you have a point? Another way of asking this is, do you think there will be at least 1-2 points from each of the lines at every intersection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155219/discussion-between-srik-and-jeremy-mcgibbon).

Comment: Sounds like you want to *buffer* the lines and then compute the intersection. Can probably use shapely: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Comment: THanks @Spacedman . Sounds interesting. I didnt notice the buffer function before. So basically, would I create a bunch of buffered points (rotated about the trajectory angle), and then see which of the other set of points intersect with the buffered polygons ? If you have an example, would love to see that, otherwise ill try it out too.

Comment: Sort of - you create a buffer *polygon* (like a sausage) around your line, with the buffer width being your tolerance. If you can edit your Q to include some code to produce sample data I might get a chance to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the shapely package already has a ton of convinience functions that get me very far with this.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, MultiPoint
# I assume that self.line is of type LineString (i.e. a line trajectory)
region_polygon = self.line.buffer(self.lane_width)
# line.buffer essentially generates a nice interpolated bounding polygon around the trajectory.
# Now we can identify all the other points in the other trajectory that intersects with the region_polygon that we just generated. You can also use .intersection if you want to simply generate two polygon trajectories and find the intersecting polygon as well.
is_in_region = [region_polygon.intersects(point) for point in points]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two lines defined by numpy arrays `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2`.

```
import numpy as np
```

You can create an array `distances[i, j]` containing the distances between the `i`th point in the first line and the `j`th point in the second line.

```
distances = ((x1[:, None] - x2[None, :])**2 + (y1[:, None] - y2[None, :])**2)**0.5
```

Then you can find indices where `distances` is less than some threshold you want to define for intersection. If you're thinking of the lines as having some thickness, the threshold would be half of that thickness.

```
threshold = 0.1
intersections = np.argwhere(distances < threshold)
```

`intersections` is now a N by 2 array containing all point pairs that are considered to be "intersecting" (the `[i, 0]` is the index from the first line, and `[i, 1]` is the index from the second line). If you want to get the set of all the indices from each line that are intersecting, you can use something like

```
first_intersection_indices = np.asarray(sorted(set(intersections[:, 0])))
second_intersection_indices = np.asarray(sorted(set(intersections[:, 1])))
```

From here, you can also determine how many intersections there are by taking only the center value for any consecutive values in each list.

```
L1 = []
current_intersection = []
for i in range(first_intersection_indices.shape[0]):
    if len(current_intersection) == 0:
        current_intersection.append(first_intersection_indices[i])
    elif first_intersection_indices[i] == current_intersection[-1]:
        current_intersection.append(first_intersection_indices[i])
    else:
        L1.append(int(np.median(current_intersection)))
        current_intersection = [first_intersection_indices[i]]
print(len(L1))
```

You can use these to print the coordinates of each intersection.

```
for i in L1:
    print(x1[i], y1[i])
```

Comment: Thanks! Great alternate approach of finding close points as an approximate to the intersection points to two polygons. One concern - if the sampling of points are somewhat "unlucky" (since the interpolation between points are not considered), this approach might not find intersections when in reality there would be intersections. Is this accurate?